# Sorting in not working in angularJS using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to sort my table if I am using ng-repeat to create header.

I have listed my issue at http://plnkr.co/edit/5vjsRdRLTFgXhvqHVkWA?p=preview

On click of header table sorting should happen, but it is not working fine.

### HTML Code :

```
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])" ng-click="predicate = key; reverse=!reverse;">
          {{key}}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search[key]"  />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in colors | filter:search | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
          <td ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(item)">{{item[key]}}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

### JS Code :

```
  $scope.search = {};

  $scope.colors = [{
    'id': 1,
    'productId': 1001,
    'productName': 'prd 1',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-01T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'productId': 1002,
    'productName': 'prd 2',
    'minimumLevel': 23,
    'price': 12.54,
    'productDate': '2014-11-02T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'productId': 1003,
    'productName': 'prd 3',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-04T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'productId': 1004,
    'productName': 'prd 4',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-22T06:41:30.809Z'
  }, {
    'id': 5,
    'productId': 1005,
    'productName': 'prd 5',
    'minimumLevel': 2,
    'price': 12.50,
    'productDate': '2014-11-18T06:41:30.809Z'
  }];

  $scope.getKeysOfCollection = function(obj) {
    obj = angular.copy(obj);
    if (!obj) {
      return [];
    }
    return Object.keys(obj);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope, therefore `predicate` and `reverse` are being updated in the scope of the first `ng-repeat`, but they are not available in the scope of the second `ng-repeat`.

A possible way to fix this would be:

Define `predicate` and `reverse` as properties of your controller, like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.predicate='id';
  this.reverse=false;
  ...
```

And change your view like this:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  Predicate: {{predicate}}
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])" 
            ng-click="ctrl.predicate = key; ctrl.reverse=!ctrl.reverse;">
          {{key}}
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(colors[0])">
          <input type="text" ng-model="search[key]"  />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in colors|filter:search|orderBy:ctrl.predicate:ctrl.reverse">
       <td ng-repeat="key in getKeysOfCollection(item)">{{item[key]}}</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
```

## [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bn10vHMqpJHcpW7sWFFR?p=preview)

Comment: I have one more issue regarding sorting icons, if I click header I am not able to show proper sorted icon : http://plnkr.co/edit/UonOgNz0s16iKJkWLwyg?p=preview

Comment: @SachinKumbharkar I'm not sure, but I think that what you are trying to do is this: http://plnkr.co/edit/d1O7kWOqvFxLJ8mqIFLY?p=preview